# How to increment a number according to the year and month

Tags: c#

I am storing an int in the database in the format yyMM001 where "yy" is the last two digits of the current year, "MM" is the current month in two digits and last three digits should increase from 001 till the month end. and the next month MM value should be change to the current months digits and last three digits should restarts from 001 again.
Below is the code :

```
        string year = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yy");
        string month = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("MM");
        int no = 0;
        string frmno;
        IUD.Query = "Select MAX(Form_No) AS Form_No From tbl_Students";
        DataTable dtfm = IUD.FetchToDataBase();
        if (dtfm.Rows.Count > 0 && dtfm.Rows[0]["Form_No"].ToString() != string.Empty)
        {
            no = int.Parse(dtfm.Rows[0]["Form_No"].ToString()) + 1;
            return no;
        }
        else
        {
            frmno = year + month + "001";
            no = int.Parse(frmno);
            return no;
        }
```

What way should I use in the `if` condition to check the current month and change the months digits and last three digits should be restart from 001?
Please help me if anyone knows. Thanks

Comment: Split the string into substring with yyMM part in one and ### in the next. parse ### to int and then increment. recreate a string with the yyMM part and incremented number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question, this code should work for you. If the month and year match, it takes the value and increments it by 1. If not, it starts again at 001.

```
var yearMon = dtfm.Rows[0].ToString().Substring(0,4);
if (yearMon == DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMM")) {
    no = dtfm.Rows[0] + 1; //assuming the database column is an int and not a varchar
} else {
    no = Int32.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMM001"));
}

return no;
```

Or, using numbers instead of strings

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var decade = now.Year % 100;
var month = now.Month;
var decadeMonth = decade * 100 + month;

no = dtfm.Rows[0] / 1000 == decadeMonth ? dtfm.Rows[0] + 1 : decadeMonth * 1000 + 1;
```

The performance difference is negligible between the two, but the numbers version is slightly faster.

Comment: Thank you, this is the code which I need exactly. 
.Substring(0,4) is the way which I need to get the first 4 digits. Thanks for this help.

Answer (score 1):

This method once given the current Forn_No will generate the next one

```
public static string getNext(string Form_No) {
    //Template: {YY}{MM}001 to {YY}{MM}999
    var next = "";
    var prefix = Form_No.Substring(0, 4);
    var nextNumber = Int32.Parse(Form_No.Substring(4)) + 1;
    var aux = nextNumber.ToString("D3");
    next = string.Format("{0}{1}", prefix, aux);
    return next;
}
```

And used like this

```
var date = System.DateTime.Now;
string prefix = date.ToString("yyMM");
string frmno;
IUD.Query = "Select MAX(Form_No) AS Form_No From tbl_Students WHERE Form_No LIKE " + prefix + "%";
DataTable dtfm = IUD.FetchToDataBase();
if (dtfm.Rows.Count > 0 && dtfm.Rows[0]["Form_No"].ToString() != string.Empty)
{
    var max = dtfm.Rows[0]["Form_No"].ToString();
    frmno = getNext(max);
    return frmno;
}
else
{
    frmno = prefix + "001";
    return frmno;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < 999 + 1; i++)
            {
                var yy =DateTime.Now.ToString("yy");
                var mm = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM");

                var num = $"{yy}{mm}{i.ToString("D3"),3}";
                Console.WriteLine(num);
            }
```

you just need to make `$"{yy}{MM}{yourNumber}"`;

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off converting your custom number to a `DateTime`, adding a day, and then converting back to your custom format.

Converting from your custom format to a `DateTime`

```
int myCustomDate = 1606016;  // June 16, 16

int day = myCustomDate % 1000;
int month = (myCustomDate / 1000) % 100;
// Somehow you have to give it a century. Since you're using 2-digit years,
// I'll assume current century.
int year = 2000 + (myCustomDate / 100000);
DateTime dt = new DateTime(year, month, day);


dt.AddDays(1);

// then convert back to your number
int newCustomDate = (100000 * dt.Year) + (1000 * dt.Month) + dt.Day;
```

Comment: Thanks sir to give your time to suggest me the solution. But another code worked for me well.